# Loud Bathroom Fan

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

Moved into a house with one particular bathroom being small and the fan is extremely loud.  Looks like it’s a nutone 350AN B Unit (50CFM and 4 sones) and having issues finding a compatible replacement with 2 sones or less.  Housing is 8” x 7 1/4” with a 3” duct.

Spoke with nutone and they confirmed nothing they have will suffice unless I change the duct to 4” which I am trying to avoid.

Does anyone have any ideas of another brand or suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: This will likely get closed as "shopping questions are off-topic", because the answer will likely be obsolete in a year or two as models change.

Comment: Gotcha I didn’t realize. Is there a better place that you can think of to ask this?

Comment: @Jason7613 try here https://www.diychatroom.com/whats-new/posts/1240942/

Comment: Option, replace the fan switch with variable speed switch to slow it down

Comment: @Ruskes 50 CFM is at the low-end for a bathroom exhaust fan. Slowing it down will likely make it ineffective.

Comment: @Jason7613 No. This really is the best place to ask. For better or worse, the rules (which have some logic to them) discourage this type of question. I tried to answer it in a way that can be useful to others in the future, which is the key.

Comment: Appreciate it all!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact but it will also reduce the noise if no other solution is available

Answer (score 3):

Answering as a general guide to this problem. Specific models will change over time.

I see 5 different constraints. Sometimes you need to lower your constraints a bit to find something that works:

- Brand - Nutone is a major brand (I have some of their bathroom fans), but there are plenty of others around, and an exhaust fan is not an iPhone or other super-complex object - it is a fan in a box - so picking a different brand is fine. Buy based on specifications.
- Capacity - 50 CFM (or more)
- Noise Level - 2 Sones or less
- Ceiling Opening - 8" x 7-1/4"
- Duct Size - 3"

Forget the brand. Nobody but you will ever know or care. It does matter for spare parts, so note the brand and model # somewhere. But other than that, it doesn't matter.

Capacity matters. If your existing fan isn't really up to the task, look for 70 or 80 CFM or possibly more.

Noise level is important, and appears to be your biggest concern. The good news is that manufacturers large and small have improved the sound levels in recent years.

Ceiling opening might seem like a big deal. But it isn't. If you get a slightly larger fan (which is often needed to get a larger motor for higher capacity (CFM)) then you just cut a little more into the ceiling drywall. Actually, if your ceiling is concrete then this is an issue. But for most of us with drywall, plaster, etc. it is just not a problem. If the new fan is smaller then you have to patch a bit.

Duct size is a big issue. That's because higher capacity normally requires a 4" duct, and lower noise levels are often partially based on using a larger duct. Replacing the ductwork is often a big ordeal (I know I wouldn't want to do that in my attic).

So now we're down to:

- Capacity - 50 CFM *or more*
- Noise Level - 2 Sones *or less*
- Ceiling Opening - 8" x 7-1/4" *or larger*
- Duct Size - 3" *exactly*

And then you start shopping. In a quick search at Home Depot (no connection except that I shop there myself), I easily found:

- [Hampton Bay 50 CFM, 1 Sone, 7.25" x 11.5", 3" Duct](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-50-CFM-Wall-Ceiling-Mount-Roomside-Installation-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-ENERGY-STAR-7114-01/206159603)
- [Delta Breez 70 CFM, 2 Sones, 7.5" x 10.75", 3" Duct](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-Breez-Slim-Series-70-CFM-Wall-or-Ceiling-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-ENERGY-STAR-SLM70/204347757) Actually, this one has confusing dimensions - it may be 7.25" instead of 10.75", but looks like with a design where it would hide the larger hole.

There are plenty of others, and I'm sure Lowes and other stores have similar options with other brands. Double-check the installation manual (usually available online, which helps a lot) to be sure about the size of the ceiling opening.

Comment: Great I didn’t really think about cutting a bigger hole into the ceiling - more just looking for an easy replacement but it’s looking like that may not happen.  I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Jason7613 be careful in just cutting bigger hole in the ceiling

Comment: +1 for describing the thought process. (Even though I VtC as a shopping question.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative may just be to replace the blower. Nutone used a few different mounting styles,but I didn't have much trouble guessing which matched the old enclosure. Just in case, I bought it from a supplier that would let me return it if it didn't fit.

It was a bit awkward to remove and reinstall the fan and motor while working overhead, but at least the electrical connection was easy; it simply plugged into a socket in the housing.

New fan is quieter, *and* is rated for more airflow per minute (though that's also affected by duct resistance).

Not necessarily the best solution, but it saved me a few bucks.